# can't get correct results from this jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following bit of javascript and have tried a number of different ways to get the text from the div with the class dvservicestitle, and any li tags in the div with the dvservicescontent class. Neither work and I'm not sure why. Anyone have an idea what's wrong with this code?

```
if (html == "") html = "<div class='dvservicestitle'>Our Services</div><div class='dvservicescontent'><ul></ul></div>";

var title = $(html).find(".dvservicestitle");
var elements = $("dvservicescontent li", $(html));
```

Comment: "Neither work" is not a problem description. Some effort please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the `find()` method finds children nodes on the current node. Your HTML variable IS the div that you are looking for so the `find()` method doesn't find it. You need to wrap it in another container.

```
html = "<div class='dvservicestitle'>Our Services</div><div class='dvservicescontent'><ul></ul></div>";
$(html).find(".dvservicestitle")
>> []

$(html).hasClass("dvservicestitle")
>> true

html = "<div><div class='dvservicestitle'>Our Services</div><div class='dvservicescontent'><ul></ul></div></div>"

$(html).find(".dvservicestitle")
>> [<div class=​"dvservicestitle">​Our Services​</div>​]
```

Comment: Thank you.  It was the surrounding div that was giving me difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
var title = $(".dvservicestitle").text();
var elements = $(".dvservicescontent li").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find` searches descendants which you don't have. The div to search exists at top level, so it is one of the elements in the jQuery object.

Use `.filter` to filter the correct element:

```
$(html).filter(".dvservicestile").text();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var title = $(html).find(".dvservicestitle").html();
var elements = $(html).find('.dvservicescontent ul').children();
```

Comment: LOL  I brushed the enter key and did an edit. Inside of 60 seconds two people decide to be harsh.

Comment: The "enter" key does not submit an answer from within a textbox. It generates a newline. And your answer still contains no explanation or context. Just dumps two lines of code. Not wholly useful for learning.